# Querying from multiple tables based on runtime values

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have a schema that models as follows:
[image]

There can be multiple child entities for one base entity, mapped by BaseChild. On my application side, while persisting the `Base` entity, I persist the corresponding child entities.

For eg:

- Persist `Base(id=1)` in Base table alongwith:

  - `(ChildName='A', ChildValue=1)` for Child1 entity.
  - `(ChildName='B', ChildValue='char')` for Child2 entity.
  - `(ChildName='C', ChildValue=datetime())` for Child3 entity.
  - `(ChildName='D', ChildValue=5)` for Child1 entity.
- Persist `Base(id=2)` in Base table alongwith:

  - `(ChildName='E', ChildValue=2)` for Child1 entity.
  - `(ChildName='A', ChildValue=3)` for Child1 entity.
  - `(ChildName='F', ChildValue='char')` for Child2 entity.

After persisting in the respective tables,

Base table

```
+----+
| id |
+----+
|  1 |
|  2 |
+----+
```

BaseChild Table

```
+----------------------+
| id base_id ChildName |
+----------------------+
| 1    1        A      |
| 2    1        B      |
| 3    1        C      |
| 4    1        D      |
| 5    2        E      |
| 6    2        A      |
| 7    2        F      |
+----------------------+
```

Child1 Table

```
+---------------+
| id ChildValue |
+---------------+
| 1  1          |
| 4  5          |
| 5  2          |
| 6  3          |
+---------------+
```

Child2 Table

```
+---------------+
| id ChildValue |
+---------------+
| 2    'char'   |
| 7    'char'   |
+---------------+
```

Child3 Table

```
+---------------+
| id ChildValue |
+---------------+
| 3  datetime() |
+---------------+
```

Now, on my application side, I recieve a query to get the `id` of `Base` entity based on the List of `(ChildName, ChildValue)` values.

Basically the reverse operation, now I have a list of child entities and I want to find the Base entity corresponding to that. (Do note that the number of child entities is not fixed, as in the example for `Base(id=1)` there are 4 child entities but for `Base(id=2)` there are 3 child entities)

Let's continue with the previous example. I recieve a query saying,
find the `id` of base entity for `(ChildName, ChildValue)` corresponding to `(E,2)` in Child1,
`(A,3)` in Child1 and `(F,'char')` in Child2.

For this query, it should fetch `Base(id=2)`.

Any ideas how should I model this dynamic query in sql server?

I am open to any ideas of having a denormalized view over the tables or performing intersects over the results. Also, I want all the computation to be done on the database side and not on my application side.

Comment: These are pk/fk relationships.  The word "entity" is not needed.  Imo it would helpful to explain what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: There are other relationships with Base table on Base table's `id`. But the queries recieved are of type `List<Childs>`. So I am trying to find the `id` in Base table corresponding to Childs and then use that `id` for further processing.

Comment: From the database design perspective it would be ideal to map Childs objects to columns in a table.  Not have a separate table for each Child.

Comment: `map Childs objects to columns in a table`. You mean have a column for every child in base table itself? Then issue arises with having nulls and also there can be multiple Child objects for each child(as in the example, there are `2` entries in `Child1` for `Base(id=1)`), so per field it would be an array instead of single fields.

Comment: Not "a column for every child object in base table itself" but rows in a table(s) which contain columns which sufficiently define the object(s) such that you can get any array back you want using a query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can construct the query using `exists`:

```
with c1 as (
      select bc.base_id, bc.childname, c1.*
      from child1 c1 join
           basechild bc
           on bc.id = c1.childvalue
     ),
     c2 as (
      select bc.base_id, bc.childname, c1.*
      from child1 c1 join
           basechild bc
           on bc.id = c1.childvalue
     )
select b.*
from base b
where exists (select 1
              from c1
              where c1.baseid = b.id and
                    c1.childname = 'E' and
                    c1.childvalue = 2
             ) and      
      exists (select 1
              from c1
              where c1.baseid = b.id and
                    c1.childname = 'A' and
                    c1.childvalue = 3
             ) and      
      exists (select 1
              from c2
              where c2.baseid = b.id and
                    c2.childname = 'F' and
                    c2.childvalue = 'char'
             );
```

Comment: Thank you, I used the above query logic and created a native query on my application side based on the type of child entities for the given base entity.